Redis transaction and watch - need for it
I don't understand the need for watch in Redis, if I assume that redis queues transaction commands and executes them all at one shot without interleaving with other requests (since it is single threaded), why is there a need for watch?
(I tried to check their documentation but couldn't find my answer, if they have mentioned how it works internally that reference would also help)
